# What filename does auto_initramfs look for?

Tags: boot, config.txt

From the config.txt documentation:

> If auto_initramfs is set to 1, look for an initramfs file using the same rules as the kernel selection.

Presumably it's looking for something with either no suffix, `7`, `7l`, or `8`, but what is the base name for that?

`update-initramfs` generates files named `initrd.img-$(uname -r)`, but it's not that.

Neither `initrd.img` nor `imitramfs.img` are loaded for `kernel.img`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The new Bookworm-based image (2023-10-10) comes with `auto_initramfs=1` and pre-built files named `initramfs`, `initramfs7`, `initramfs7l`, and `initramfs8`. These load as expected to match the kernel.

However, this does not work with any of the previous images. The same setup on the 2023-05-03 Bullseye-based image fails to load any initramfs.

Comment: You can make an initramfs with `sudo mkinitramfs` so what's the problem?

Comment: @Dougie that it is not loaded with `auto_initramfs=1` when using any base image before the one released this month.